# Kubectl behind proxy

Tags: kubectl, kubeconfig

I have a k8s cluster deployed in a public cloud whose api server is accessible via public IPs. I typically interact with my cluster via kubectl and I have two scenarios for how it is done:

1. From home
2. From the office

#1 works fine and causes no issues
#2 is a problem because the office network sends traffic through a proxy and injects a self signed cert. As a result I get "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" errors.

At the moment I have found two workarounds:

1. Include the `--insecure-skip-tls-verify` option for each command
2. Update my cluster definition in kubeconfig to include `insecure-skip-tls-verify: true`

While both work, I am looking for a superior solution.

I know that kubeconfig allows the specification of a `certificate-authority` to be used when connecting to a cluster but I am not sure how to get it to work.
Specifically:

1. Since the CA will be different depending on whether I connect from home or the office, can I specify two CA's?
2. How do I get the CA being used from the office and convert it to a file that I can use with the `certificate-authority` key?

Comment: Did you check https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/sharing-clusters/?

Comment: @KFC_ I don't see anything at that link specific to my problem. Is there something in particular I should look at?